# Difference between system of differential equations and maps in the context of dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems

In Stephen Wiggins' "Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos," a distinction is made between systems of equations in the form
$$\dot{x}=f(x,t)$$
and
$$x \mapsto{} g(x)$$
Quite frankly, I don't understand what the latter expression means other than the fact that it is called a map. My understanding is that the first expression, for let's say $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, is equivalent to the system
$$ \dot{x}_1 = f_1(x_1, x_2, t) $$
$$ \dot{x}_2 = f_2(x_1, x_2, t) $$

There is a clear derivative (the $\dot{x}$) in the first expression but I don't see any derivatives in the second. So my question: what does the second method of describing a dynamical system, called a map, mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamical system defined by a map uses discrete rather than continuous time steps. That is all. The dynamics are given by
$$ x_{t+1} = g\left( x_t \right) $$

Comment: That...is much simpler than I would've thought. Thanks for the clarification!

So a fixed point of a map would be when $g(x_t)=x_t$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any solution to $g(x)=x$ is a fixed point.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I can get past chapter 1. :)